# printout lexemes and tokens of a C code with using flex

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

i'm trying to print out lexemes and tokens with using lexical analyzer "flex" and the problem is i can find lexemes and can just print tokens not lexemes. this is the simple code which i use as you can see below

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
char RW[] = "RESERVE_WORD";
%}

int [i][n][t]
%%
int printf("%s --> %s\n",  yylex(), RW);
.|\n    {   /* Ignore all other */}
%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
yylex();
fclose(yyin);
return 0;
}
```

when i make a lexical analysis this yylex() function returns "null" and it says

```
example5.l:8:1: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat].
```

i will be glad if you can help me. and thanks anyway

Comment: Actually no, the warning comes from compiling the scanner.  You seem to have a gross misunderstanding of how to use yylex () which can be solved by looking at the fine manual :-).  What exactly are your input and expected output?

Comment: yeap you are true. and i handled it. i realized yylex() returns an integer so there is yytext variable which includes last token as a string. and thanks for response

Comment: Could you then please post an answer with working code so that others can see how you solved it?

Comment: yeap sure i forgot it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i handled the problem. so the thing is we should use `yytext` variable which contains the last token of the lexical analyzer as a string. In Addition, `yylex()` function will return either the value of the next token or a number <= 0 indicating EOF.

Comment: Not quite right: yylex () will return either the value of the next token or a number <= 0 indicating EOF.